# How can I get the Shutter Actuations/Count for my Nikon D5300?

Tags: nikon, shutter, shutter-actuations, nikon-d5300

I recently purchased Nikon D5300 with 18-140mm lens. Just love the image quality this camera produces.

I want to know my shutter actuations,  for which I downloaded Opanda IExif 2.3 software, but when I open the photos clicked with this camera, I do not get the "Total Number of Shutter Releases for Camera" entry itself.

When I opened the photos clicked using Nikon D5100 (friend's camera), it was showing the "Total Number of Shutter Releases for Camera" entry under "MakerNote (Nikon)" section.

Do anyone else face the same problem with Nikon D5300 or am I missing some settings in the camera?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way would be to upload an image to [CameraShutterCount](http://www.camerashuttercount.com/) which will do it for you.

Alternatively, using the freeware, cross-platform [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) you can extract the data either by reading through the whole lot looking for "shutter count"
`exiftool DSC_1000.jpg`
or with a little filtering
`exiftool DSC_1000.jpg | /find /I "Shutter Count"`
Which should return something along the lines of
`shutter count:     54321`

...though I can't get the filter to work on my Mac

On Mac, you can open the image in Preview, then from Tools > Show Inspector, then click the `i` & there should be a tab with your Camera type. Shutter Count is listed in there.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to use the Opanda software? Could you use an online tool to determine the shutter count? A quick google search suggests a few suitable tools: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=shutter+actuations

Typically you upload a JPEG or NEF file and the shutter count is provided.

If one or more of these tools also don't work it would suggest the D5300 uses a newer version of RAW/NEF file and you'll need to update your software when a patch becomes available.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have already tried the online tool to determine the shutter actuation. Unfortunately, even that did not work. Probably D5300 uses newer version of NEF. Is there any Nikon forum where I can post this same question?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the Opanda download is dated nearly 9 years ago.  That's ancient in techie times, but this is the same problem with many Exif viewers, far out of date, and not supported.  Be sure to check the date of any such programs.

Exif includes basic Exif data, sort of a standard part, but the good stuff (like shutter count) is in the Manufacturers Section, not part of any standard.  Nikon changes its format now and then (with new models and features - and your camera is much newer than 9 years), so you need a newer current Exif viewer, from modern times.

You can Google Shutter Count, and see a few web sites where you can upload an image and they tell you shutter count in it.

Irfanview seems to keep up with Exif, and shows shutter count.

The very best Exif Viewer (strong opinion) is ExifTool, typically updated a couple of times a month.  It is a command line program, but there is a Windows program that converts it to a Windows program, and it is very nice, and easy to use (and up to date).  It should amaze you about the content you will find in there. :)
See http://www.scantips.com/lights/exif.html for a quick summary of that procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Shutter Count via Flickr.com as well. Just upload a picture, find the "Show Exif" link on the photo details page and search for "shutter count" in the page.

Comment: Could you link to an example of a D5300 photo which shows this information?

Comment: It's not too difficult to search Flickr and find such a photo. Either that or try it out for yourself!

Comment: Sure. But it would be a much better answer if you linked to an example.

Answer (score 0):

[CameraShutterCount.com](https://www.camerashuttercount.com) claims to have been successfully tested with the D5300. All you have to do is upload a file to their site and it will tell you.

Note: you might have to upload a raw (.NEF) image to the site, rather than a JPEG image.